# What is the meaning of "Put a bullet in something"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, idioms

I have seen this sentence in a chat between people and I guess when they said "put a bullet" they have used it idiomatically. I am not sure about the meaning though.

```
A : The process is over timing
B: Putting a bullet in it. Restarting
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: just want to add that as a native English speaker I can't recall ever having heard this phrase, so it's definitely not common

Comment: Maybe it is an Australian idiom? I heard it in Australia

Answer (score 25, accepted):

"To put a bullet" in something or someone can mean to kill the person, or end the thing. In this case, it means to terminate the "process", to stop it.

Comment: In Unix tradition, the colorful term "kill" is often used to mean "terminating" a "process". Indeed the name of the system call itself to send the killing (or non-killing) bullet -  I mean "signal" -  is named `kill` (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) as well as the command to do this (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html).

Comment: @FooF Windows has an analogous command TaskKill that is often successful. Don't get me started on how the OS sometimes fails to kill a process...

Comment: Perhaps it would be worth adding that it's a reference to what happens when you shoot something with a firearm?

Comment: Also see: [STONITH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STONITH).

Answer (score 17):

> put a bullet in *something*

can mean to end or stop *something* and also

> to put *something* out of its misery

[image: here]


at a bar, it can mean to add some Bulliet bourbon *(pronounced the same as bullet)*

[image: here]
<sub>(source: [reservebar.com](http://www.reservebar.com/spree/products/198/large/BulleitBourbon.jpg?1342510913))</sub>

Comment: I think the first cartoon is a very good illustration of what many people think of when they hear the phrase "put a bullet into". I'd upvote this answer were it not for the bourbon part, which is nowhere near as prevalent and therefore (in my view, anyway) borders on irrelevancy.

Answer (score 5):

While we are giving examples, [this](https://youtu.be/au0zM3I_p3w?t=44) is my favorite:

> There was this kid I grew up with; he was younger than me. Sorta looked up to me, you know. We did our first work together, worked our way out of the street. Things were good, we made the most of it. During Prohibition, we ran molasses into Canada.  Made a fortune.
>
> As much as anyone, I loved him and trusted him.
>
> Later on, he had an idea to build a city out of a desert stop-over for GI's on the way to the West Coast. The city he invented was Las Vegas. This was a great man, a man of vision and guts. And there isn't even a plaque, or a signpost or a statue of him in that town! Someone **put a bullet** through his eye.

— *The Godfather, Part 2*

Answer (score 4):

As an addition to the other answers, a nice usage example, in a famous poem titled [Richard Cory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Cory):

> Whenever Richard Cory went down town,
>   We people on the pavement looked at him:
>   He was a gentleman from sole to crown,
>   Clean favored, and imperially slim.
>
> And he was always quietly arrayed,
>   And he was always human when he talked;
>   But still he fluttered pulses when he said,
>   "Good-morning," and he glittered when he walked.
>
> And he was rich – yes, richer than a king –
>   And admirably schooled in every grace:
>   In fine, we thought that he was everything
>   To make us wish that we were in his place.
>
> So on we worked, and waited for the light,
>   And went without the meat, and cursed the bread;
>   And Richard Cory, one calm summer night,
>   Went home and **put a bullet** through his head.

The phrase is used literally here, of course, but it's a nice poem.

This use of "put" might be not very intuitive for a novice learner. In Russian, we don't "put" a bullet, but "release" or "fire" a bullet. "Put a bullet into something" would imply (to a speaker of Russian) that we gently placed it there. With "through", it's easier to understand.

Comment: In Russian it's "пустить себе пулю в лоб" (to shoot oneself [dead]), isnt it?

Comment: @Rompey - yes, indeed. As I typed the answer, I realized that I did not provde a good translation of the Russian expression, but my general idea was that the verb "put" might seem strange to a rookie. Indeed, in Russian it is literally "to release a bullet into one's forehead".

Comment: Nice poem, really! And I've just found out that on YouTube, there's a  song based on it -- with the same title, it was recorded in 1965 by Simon and Garfunkel.

Comment: @Rompey - glad that you liked it!

Comment: Good points; however, while the primary meaning of _put_ may be to place something somewhere ("Please put that teacup down on the table," e.g.) there are plenty of [not-as-gentle alternate meanings to this versatile word](https://www.wordnik.com/words/put). For example: If don't want to be gentle with our words, we might _put something bluntly_; if we want to get our money's worth out of something, we might _put it to good use_; if we need to solve a difficult problem, we might _put our minds to it;_ if we don't want to yield in an argument, we might _put our foot down._